# Different widget layouts based on homescreen cell height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a 1x4 widget. Although the widget is designed to be flexible, different cell heights on different phones makes it look weird on some phones:

[image]

I have read [Create alternative layouts docs](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes#alternative-layouts), but I am not sure specifying, e.g., `layout-sh600dp` (smallest height of screen is 600dp, and then other variations) will solve this, because different phone homescreens can have different number of rows. So one phone with height of 600dp can have 6 rows, making one row 100dp high, while other phone with the same height of 600dp can have 4 rows, making one row 150dp high. And 50dp is a big difference.

Is there any way to have multiple widget layouts based on homescreen cell height or how do devs approach this?